# Can I assert inside a begin rescue end block?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rescue

I have something that I am testing that I will know its working if it fails.  Is there a better way to code this in ruby with test-unit than what I have in my example below?

```
begin 
  x = Method.shouldFail
  assert_true(false)
rescue Test::Unit::AssertionFailedError
  assert_true(false) #stop test, this is a failure
rescue => e
  assert_equal(400, e.code)
end
```

This seems very clunky is there a better way to write this?  I would expect that Method.shouldFail would always fail but it might not.  And I would assume that in the last rescue block e.code should always be 400 but it could be something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`assert_raise`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Test/Unit/Assertions/assert_raise) to test that particular exceptions are being thrown.

Comment: Is there a way to catch the the error raised and do something with it?